# Issue between Cordova, Firebase and cordova-plugin-googleplus

Tags: cordova, firebase, google-plus-signin

I am working on a project using Firebase and Cordova to build mobile applications.
I am using [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) to implement login function. The instruction is quite clear and easy. After install necessary plugins, generate keystore, SHA1 fingerprint, i need to go to [developers.google.com/mobile](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin) to insert SHA1 and generate configuration file.
Then go to [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) to generate a **web** client id.
Finally call this in my application:

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login(
{
  'scopes': [],       
  'webClientId': 'my-web-client-id', 
  'offline': true
},
function (obj) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
},
function (msg) {
  alert('error: ' + msg);
}
```

);

Howerver, after follow all the steps, with every client ids generated automatically by Google ( android, web ) or manually by me, i always get error 12501.
I have tried to test on cordova debug mode and released mode ( signed and unsigned ) and i still get 12501 error.

Can someone help me to fix it ?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried adding in the app (along with the SHA-1) and generating the google-services.json file in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general)? See if using the one from it would make a difference? :)

Comment: yes, i did, but it is not working. I am using SHA1 generated from debug.keystore